# Nginx + Express app in subdirectory/location, returning 404

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, node.js, http-status-code-404

I want to make an express app accessible through http://website.com/app and use nginx as a reverse proxy as well as to serve static files.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
upstream app {
    server localhost:3333;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    root /var/www/website.com;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location = / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    
    location /app/ {
        alias /var/www/app/static;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
    }

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";  
    }
}
```

index.js (located in `/var/www/app/static/`) requests some resource via `fetch("/info")`.

app.js (located in `/var/www/app/`) is supposed to deliver said resouce with

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get("/info", (req, res) => {
    res.header("Content-Type",'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(info));
})

app.listen(3333, () => {
    console.log("Server listening at http://localhost:3333")
})
```

When I visit http://mywebsite.com/app, the static files are served by nginx but `/info` is yielding a 404. Nginx error log: *"/var/www/website.com/info" failed (2: No such file or directory)*.
The express app is running (`$pm2 ls` -> status "online").

I assume that the proxy configuration is not correct or there might be a misunderstanding of how nginx and servers work on my side (these are my first steps). I would be grateful for advice.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make DNS entry for that,

Specify the location of content, add server name as site and in location content